# How to prove the following function has only one root in interval [0,1]

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

How to prove the following function has only one root in interval [0,1]:

$f(x)=(1-x^b)^b-(1-x)$ where b>1 is a positive integer

Some hint so far:
we can easily prove that $g(x)=1-x^b$ has exactly one fixed point in [0,1]
If we can proof that $g(g(x))=1-(1-x^b)^b$ has exactly one fixed point in [0,1] then the result follows.

Comment: You probably mean the open interval $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint for easier solution: $f(0) = f(1) = 0$ and $f''$ has only one root in $(0,1)$.